# "Why" is $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}] < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, soft-question, intuition

Obviously this question is a little open-ended.

A lot of complex analysis seems to work primarily because we can view $\mathbb{C}$ as a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-algebra, and apply analytic and geometric ideas which work only (or at least best) in finite-dimensional real space.

When we consider most other fields that we come across in practice (for instance, $\mathbb{F}_q$,$\mathbb{Q}_p$, or $\mathbb{Q}$) generally their algebraic closures are infinite-dimensional extensions.

Is there any intuitive reason why the way we construct $\mathbb{R}$ would suggest that we were producing a field whose algebraic closure was a finite-dimensional extension?  Does such a construction generalize to other fields in any way?

Comment: For one thing, any polynomial of odd degree has a real root...

Comment: Yeah, but if that's the only possible answer then the question is somewhat hopeless, since it doesn't seem like there's a way to generalize the IVT to other fields.  I was hoping there was a more algebraic explanation.  (Assuming that the only proof of that is to observe that an odd-degree function goes to $+\infty$ at one end and $-\infty$ at the other and apply the IVT.)

Comment: Check theorem 3.1 in this article http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf

Comment: @omar That's more or less the reply I was typing :-) (Related question @ MO: http://mathoverflow.net/q/8756/ )

Comment: The algebraic closure of a field is finite dimensional if and only if the field is real closed (and thus the dimension is 2) or is algebraically closed (and thus the dimension is 1).

Comment: I wonder if there is any proof that $[\mathbb C : \mathbb R] < \infty$ that does not also prove $[\mathbb C : \mathbb R] = 2$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't give you an "intuitive" reason why $\Bbb C$ is a finite dimensional $\Bbb R$-algebra, but I can point you toward a generalization of this fact : $\Bbb R$ is a [real closed field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field), and if $F$ is any real closed field, then $F[\sqrt{-1}]$ is algebraically closed.

**EDIT** As @omar, @Grigory and @Hurkyl pointed out in the comment section, the relevant material is the [Artin-Schreier theorem](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf).

Comment: Given the comments, I want the Artin-Schreier theorem (which is the provides the converse of what you've said here) as part of any answer I accept.  Looks like the people who mentioned it in the comments aren't going to put up an answer; want to add it to yours?

Comment: Ok, I'll add it. Since I was unaware of the Artin-Schreier theorem, I made my answer community wiki. You can accept it if you like.